# Consume SOAP service in spring-boot

Tags: web-services, spring-boot

I need to consume soap webservice in spring boot application. I found something over the internet https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/ and I tried that which results in the below exception.

I followed the below procedure for generating the java classes out of WSDL.
Project -> New -> Web Service Client -> pasted the WSDL URL -> Finish

```
2019-04-11 16:06:39.481  WARN 10268 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'marshaller' defined in class path resource [com/test/myapp/client/ProductsConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.oxm.UncategorizedMappingException: Unknown JAXB exception; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory could not be instantiated: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: "SomeWebService?wsdl" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index
- with linked exception:
[javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: "SomeWebService?wsdl" doesnt contain 
ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index]
2019-04-11 16:06:39.493  INFO 10268 --- [           main] 
o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
```

Comment: So you aren't following the guide/tutorial and ask here why it doesn't work? The tutorial is using Spring WS not a generated web client.

Comment: So what should I do now

Comment: Follow the guide, that explains what to do and what to generate. Also the error indicates that you are using the wrong configuration for your marshaller, and again aren't following the tutorial.

Comment: Now I have used the maven plugin configuration which is there in the tutorial. But I'm getting some exception at <execution> 
`Execution default of goal org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.13.1:generate failed: A required class was missing while executing 
 org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.13.1:generate: com/sun/xml/bind/api/ErrorListener`

Comment: one thing I want to tell I'm not using wsdl from my local. It is some other URL. Is that okay? and I'm using SomeWebService?wsdl -> which is a service provider and not SomeWebService.wsdl which is the actual file.

Comment: Please follow the tutorial. Judging from the error you are using JDK11 instead of JDk8 which is being used by the tutorial . JDK11 doesn't include jaxb and you need additional dependencies.

Comment: No. I'm using JDK 8

Comment: Then make sure you have the proper JAXB details. If you follow the tutorial it should work, if you use the same setup.

Comment: yeah. I googled it. instead of 0.13.1 version need to use 0.13.3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191663/discussion-between-krishna-and-m-deinum).

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem. Have you managed to solve this problem?